# javascript form validate a sub array

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Can someone please help me validate a sub array with javascript.

my form looks like this:
`<input type='text' name='variant_array[" + variantCounter + "][name]'>`
I have tried addressing it in JS like this:

```
var variantInputName = document.getElemenstByName('variant_array[][name]');
    for (i=0; i<variantInputName.length; i++) {
           alert(variantInputName[i].value);
```

Which does not work.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Cam

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `.getElemenstByName` has to be changed into `getElementsByName`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this in the future I had to use getElementById